# What kind of signal is emitted when QScrollArea entry is selected/clicked?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm having though time figuring out what kind of signal is emitted in following situation:

[image]

Basicly that's `QScrollArea` that holds multiple `QTableWidget`s:

```
class ScrollArea(QtGui.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ScrollArea, self).__init__()
        self.scroll_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scroll_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.__create_content()
        self.setWidget(self._content_widget)
        self.scroll_layout.addWidget(self)
        self.scroll_widget.setLayout(self.scroll_layout)

    def __create_content(self):
        self._content_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self._content_widget_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self._content_widget.setLayout(self._content_widget_layout)

    def add_item(self, item):
        self._content_widget_layout.addWidget(item)
```

I'm using `Plastique` style for `QApplication`. As it can be seen from the above picture, when an item is clicked inside `QScrollArea`, blue border appears. What I would like to know is which signal is emitted when the border is drawn? I need this information so I can append a row to the selected `QTableWidget` whenever a button (on the left side) is clicked.

Also you can see that there is a 'x' inside each table, when 'x' is pressed that `QTableWidget` gets removed from `QScrollArea`. If there is a solution for previous problem, I could also remove `QTableWidget` depending on user selection rather than user clicking the 'x'.

Comment: There's no signal - it indicates focus, so there's a [focus event](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfocusevent.html#details).

Comment: I think there is no need to use the focus to solve the problem of the "X" button, on the contrary it would make it more complex because it would have to be filtered, instead if you provide the code of how to create your QTableWidget with the "X" button you would get a simple solution.

Comment: Well currently I'm using `sectionClicked()` on `horizontalHeader()` and when section 2 is clicked on each horizontal header, I'm removing that particular widget from layout and calling `deleteLater()` on `QTableWidget` which works fine. I would get basicly same behaviour if i add `QPushButton` inside `horizontalHeader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the widget that has the focus you can use the `focusChanged` signal of `QApplication`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class HorizontalHeader(QtGui.QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HorizontalHeader, self).__init__(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self.button = QtGui.QToolButton(self, text="x")
        self.sectionResized.connect(self.handleSectionResized)

    def handleSectionResized(self):
        last_ix = self.count() - 1
        pos = QtCore.QPoint(self.sectionViewportPosition(last_ix) + self.sectionSize(last_ix) , 0)
        self.button.move(pos)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.handleSectionResized()
        super(HorizontalHeader, self).showEvent(event)


class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        header = HorizontalHeader(self)
        header.button.clicked.connect(self.deleteLater)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(header)
        QtGui.qApp.focusChanged.connect(self.onFocusChanged)

    def onFocusChanged(self, old, new):
        if new == self:
            self.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
    scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    scrollArea.setWidget(widget)
    lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)

    for i in range(10):
        w = TableView()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(4, 2, w)
        w.setModel(model)
        lay.addWidget(w)

    scrollArea.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```